# How to create files from a groupby object, based on the length of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, group-by

I have a dataframe (df) that looks like this (highly simplified):

```
ID  A   B   C   VALUE
1   10  462 2241    217
2   11  498 6953    217
3   67  120 6926    654
4   68  898 7153    654
5   87  557 4996    654
6   88  227 6475    911
7   47  875 5097    911
8   48  143 8953    111
9   65  157 4470    111
10  66  525 9328    111
```

The `'VALUE'` column contains a variable number of rows with identical values. I am trying to output a series of csv files that contain all of the rows that contain a `'VALUE'` length == 2, ==3 etc. For example:

```
to_csv('/Path/to/VALUE_len_2.csv')              
ID  A   B   C      VALUE
1   10  462 2241    217
2   11  498 6953    217
6   88  227 6475    911
7   47  875 5097    911
to_csv('/Path/to/VALUE_len_3.csv')              
ID  A   B   C      VALUE
3   67  120 6926    654
4   68  898 7153    654
5   87  557 4996    654
to_csv('/Path/to/VALUE_len_4.csv')              
ID  A   B   C      VALUE
7   47  875 5097    111
8   48  143 8953    111
9   65  157 4470    111
10  66  525 9328    111
```

I can get the desired output of one length value at a time, e.g., using:

```
df = pd.concat(v for _, v in df.groupby("VALUE") if len(v) == 2)
df.to_csv("/Path/to/VALUE_len_2.csv")
```

However, I have dozens of values to test. I would like to put this in a for loop on the order of:

```
mylist = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] or len([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
grouped = df.groupby(['VALUE'])
output = '/Path/to/VALUE_len_{}.csv'

for loop here:
    if item in my list found in grouped:
        output rows to csv
    else:
        pass
```

- I've tried various constructions to iterate the groupby object using the items in the list, and I haven't been able to make anything work.
- It might be an issue with trying to use a groupby object this way, but it is more than likely it is my inability to get the syntax right to complete the iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It doesn't make sense to use a predetermined list to create the filenames.
- `df_len` will be used to generate a filename using an `f-string`.
- [`Path.exists()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.exists) is used to determine if the file exists or not

```py
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

# test data
data = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'A': [10, 11, 67, 68, 87, 88, 47, 48, 65, 66], 'B': [462, 498, 120, 898, 557, 227, 875, 143, 157, 525], 'C': [2241, 6953, 6926, 7153, 4996, 6475, 5097, 8953, 4470, 9328], 'VALUE': [217, 217, 654, 654, 654, 911, 911, 111, 111, 111]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# groupby value
for group, data in df.groupby('VALUE'):
    
    # get the length of the dataframe
    df_len = len(data)
    
    # create a filename with df_len
    file = Path(f'/path/to/VALUE_len_{df_len}.csv')
    
    # if the file exists, append without the header
    if file.exists():
        data.to_csv(file, index=False, mode='a', header=False)
        
    # create a new file
    else:
        data.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

---

- If you must only create a file for dataframes of a specific length

```py
desired_length = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

# groupby value
for group, data in df.groupby('VALUE'):
    
    # get the length of the dataframe
    df_len = len(data)
    
    # create a filename with df_len
    file = Path(f'/path/to/VALUE_len_{df_len}.csv')
    
    # check if the length of the dataframe is in the desired length
    if df_len in desired_length:
        
        # if the file exists, append without the header
        if file.exists():
            data.to_csv(file, index=False, mode='a', header=False)

        # create a new file
        else:
            data.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I see the error in my logic with my earlier attempts. I wanted to create a file of dataframes of particular lengths to save on processing time and disk space since there are potentially 3K lengths in this 800,000+ row data set and I will periodically just need a subset. I also appreciate the edit of my question title to make it more meaningful. Thanks again.

Comment: @2kb You're welcome. I'm glad this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# find the VALUE_len of every VALUE first
df['VALUE_len'] = df.groupby('VALUE')['ID'].transform('count')
cols = df.columns[:-1]
# ['ID', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'VALUE']

# save group by VALUE_len
for VALUE_len, group in df.groupby('VALUE_len'):
    file = Path(f'/path/to/VALUE_len_{VALUE_len}.csv')
    group[cols].to_csv(file, index=False)
```